# Automating (loops) Euclidean distance measurements in R

Tags: r, loops, automation, export-to-csv, euclidean-distance

**AIM:** I want to automate (loop) the code below, without having to manually run it for each sample. I have a terrible habit of writing long-hand in base, and need to start using loops, which I find difficult to implement.

**DATA:** I have two data frames: one of the sample data (**samples**), and one of reference data (**ref**).
They both contain the same variables (**x, y, z**).

**CODE DESCRIPTION:** For each sample (sample$sample_name), I want to calculate it's Euclidean distance to each case in the reference data. The results are then used to re-order the reference data, to show which points are 'closest' to the sample data point, in the Euclidean (3-dimensional) space.

My current code allows me to simply substitute the sample name (i.e. "s1") and then re-run the code, making one final change for the filename of the .csv file. The output is a list of the reference data in order of closest proximity to the sample (in the Euclidean space).

I would like to automate the process (into a loop?), so that I can simply run it on the two data frames using the list of sample names (samples$sample_name), and hopefully also automate the exporting to a .csv file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
# Reference data
country<-c("Austria","Austria","Italy","Italy","Turkey","Romania","France")
x<-c(18.881,18.881,18.929,19.139,19.008,19.083,18.883)
y<-c(15.627,15.627,15.654,15.772,15.699,15.741,15.629)
z<-c(38.597,38.597,38.842,39.409,39.048,39.224,38.740)
pb_age<-c(-106,-106,-87,-6,-55,-26,-104)
ref<-data.frame(country,x,y,z,pb_age) # Reference data

# Sample data (for euclidean measurements against Reference data)
sample_name<-c("s1","s2","s3")
x2<-c(18.694,18.729,18.731)
y2<-c(15.682,15.683,15.677)
z2<-c(38.883,38.989,38.891)
pb_age2<-c(120,97,82)
samples<-data.frame(sample_name,x2,y2,z2,pb_age2) # Sample data
colnames(samples)<-c("sample_name","x","y","z","pb_age") # To match Reference data headings

# Euclidean distance measurements
library(fields) # Need package for Euclidean distances

# THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO AUTOMATE/LOOP (BELOW)...
# Currently, I have to update the 'id' for each sample to get a result (for each sample)

id<-"s1"  # Sample ID - this is simply changed so the following code can be re-run for each sample

# The code
x1<-samples[which(samples$sample_name==id),c("x","y","z")]
x2<-ref[,c("x","y","z")]

result_distance<-rdist(x1,x2) # Computing the Euclidean distance
result_distance<-as.vector(result_distance) # Saving the results as a vector

euclid_ref<-data.frame(result_distance,ref) # Creating a new data.frame adding the Euclidean distances to the original Reference data
colnames(euclid_ref)[1]<-"euclid_distance" # Updating the column name for the result

# Saving and exporting the results
results<-euclid_ref[order(euclid_ref$euclid_distance),] # Re-ordering the data.frame by the euclide distances, smallest to largest
write.csv(results, file="s1.csv")   # Ideally, I want the file name to be the same as the SAMPLE id, i.e. s1, s2, s3...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A loop would be simple enough, but a more R-like solution would be to take advantage of vectorization and the apply-family of functions:

```
result_distances <- data.frame(t(rdist(samples[, 2:4], ref[, 2:4])), ref)
colnames(result_distances)[1:3] <- rep("euclid_distance", 3)
# str(result_distances)
# 'data.frame': 7 obs. of  8 variables:
#  $ euclid_distance: num  0.346 0.346 0.24 0.695 0.355 ...
#  $ euclid_distance: num  0.424 0.424 0.25 0.594 0.286 ...
#  $ euclid_distance: num  0.334 0.334 0.205 0.666 0.319 ...
#  $ country        : chr  "Austria" "Austria" "Italy" "Italy" ...
#  $ x              : num  18.9 18.9 18.9 19.1 19 ...
#  $ y              : num  15.6 15.6 15.7 15.8 15.7 ...
#  $ z              : num  38.6 38.6 38.8 39.4 39 ...
#  $ pb_age         : num  -106 -106 -87 -6 -55 -26 -104
```

Normally we would not give multiple columns the same name, but we are planning to pull them out next:

```
results <- lapply(1:3, function(i) data.frame(result_distances[order(result_distances[, i]), c(i, 4:8)]))
names(results) <- samples$sample_name
```

Now we have a list called `results` with three data frames named "s1", "s2", and "s3". Lists make it easy to apply a function to many sets of similarly organized data. For example `results[["s1"]]` or `results[[1]]` prints the data frame for the first sample. Now we write out the results:

```
sapply(names(results), function(x) write.csv(results[[x]], file=paste0(x, ".csv")))
```

This will create 3 files, "s1.csv", "s2.csv", "s3.csv".

Comment: Thank you for this [tag:dcarlson]. This is a neat way to incorporate the results into the data frame for quick re-ordering/analysis in R - also tight on the code front!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a loop that computes Euclidean distances for all samples from the reference data locations, using your original input data and the key parts of your code. It's a little more verbose than the vectorised-apply solution, but perhaps is a bit easier to read because it is less terse and nested. The final output is a single data frame.

```
# prepare an empty list object to store the results
output <- vector("list", length = nrow(samples))

  # this is the start of the loop
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(samples))){
   # we can read this as 'for row i of the samples dataframe, do this...'

    # get coords for sample i
    sample_coords <- samples[i ,c("x","y","z")]
    
    # get coords for all reference locations
    # this line would be fine above the loop
    # since it gives the same result for each 
    # iteration. I place it here to echo your
    # original workflow
    ref_coords <- ref[,c("x","y","z")]
    
    # compute Euclidean distance and coerce to vector, 
    e_dist_vec <- as.vector(rdist(sample_coords, ref_coords))
    
    # store in data frame
    e_dist_ref_df <- data.frame(e_dist_vec,  ref) 
    
    # update colname
    colnames(e_dist_ref_df)[1] <- "euclid_distance"
    
    # order df by euclid_distance values
    results <- e_dist_ref_df[order(e_dist_ref_df$euclid_distance),]
    
    #  store results for sample i in the list
    output[[i]] <- results
    
  } # this is the end of the loop


# assign sample names to list items
names(output) <- samples$sample_name
```

At this point we have a list of data frames (one per sample), which you could write to individual CSVs (like we see in @dcarlson's answer), one file per data frame, or we can continue an put them all in one data frame for downstream analysis, etc. Here's how the list output from the loop looks:

```
> output
$s1
  euclid_distance country      x      y      z pb_age
3       0.2401874   Italy 18.929 15.654 38.842    -87
7       0.2428559  France 18.883 15.629 38.740   -104
1       0.3461069 Austria 18.881 15.627 38.597   -106
2       0.3461069 Austria 18.881 15.627 38.597   -106
5       0.3551197  Turkey 19.008 15.699 39.048    -55
6       0.5206563 Romania 19.083 15.741 39.224    -26
4       0.6948388   Italy 19.139 15.772 39.409     -6

$s2
  euclid_distance country      x      y      z pb_age
3       0.2499000   Italy 18.929 15.654 38.842    -87
5       0.2856186  Turkey 19.008 15.699 39.048    -55
7       0.2977129  France 18.883 15.629 38.740   -104
1       0.4241509 Austria 18.881 15.627 38.597   -106
2       0.4241509 Austria 18.881 15.627 38.597   -106
6       0.4288415 Romania 19.083 15.741 39.224    -26
4       0.5936506   Italy 19.139 15.772 39.409     -6

$s3
  euclid_distance country      x      y      z pb_age
3       0.2052657   Italy 18.929 15.654 38.842    -87
7       0.2195655  France 18.883 15.629 38.740   -104
5       0.3191583  Turkey 19.008 15.699 39.048    -55
1       0.3338203 Austria 18.881 15.627 38.597   -106
2       0.3338203 Austria 18.881 15.627 38.597   -106
6       0.4887627 Romania 19.083 15.741 39.224    -26
4       0.6661929   Italy 19.139 15.772 39.409     -6
```

Often it's convenient to have it in a single data frame for further analysis, here's one way to do that:

```
# bind list dfs into one big data frame, not sure what the one-line equivalent in base R is
output_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(output, .id = "sample_id")
```

Here's how the final product looks:

```
> output_df
   sample_id euclid_distance country      x      y      z pb_age
1         s1       0.2401874   Italy 18.929 15.654 38.842    -87
2         s1       0.2428559  France 18.883 15.629 38.740   -104
3         s1       0.3461069 Austria 18.881 15.627 38.597   -106
4         s1       0.3461069 Austria 18.881 15.627 38.597   -106
5         s1       0.3551197  Turkey 19.008 15.699 39.048    -55
6         s1       0.5206563 Romania 19.083 15.741 39.224    -26
7         s1       0.6948388   Italy 19.139 15.772 39.409     -6
8         s2       0.2499000   Italy 18.929 15.654 38.842    -87
9         s2       0.2856186  Turkey 19.008 15.699 39.048    -55
10        s2       0.2977129  France 18.883 15.629 38.740   -104
11        s2       0.4241509 Austria 18.881 15.627 38.597   -106
12        s2       0.4241509 Austria 18.881 15.627 38.597   -106
13        s2       0.4288415 Romania 19.083 15.741 39.224    -26
14        s2       0.5936506   Italy 19.139 15.772 39.409     -6
15        s3       0.2052657   Italy 18.929 15.654 38.842    -87
16        s3       0.2195655  France 18.883 15.629 38.740   -104
17        s3       0.3191583  Turkey 19.008 15.699 39.048    -55
18        s3       0.3338203 Austria 18.881 15.627 38.597   -106
19        s3       0.3338203 Austria 18.881 15.627 38.597   -106
20        s3       0.4887627 Romania 19.083 15.741 39.224    -26
21        s3       0.6661929   Italy 19.139 15.772 39.409     -6
```

Comment: Thanks for this [tag:Ben] - this is nice and easy to follow, and actually helps a lot with me understanding loops and the previous workaround by [tag:dcarlson]. Printing the output in R, as you do, is actually really useful for a quick visual of nearest neighbours - I do this a lot - so it's very useful! I would like to accept both answers as useful (both have their strengths) - but it only let's me tick one!

Comment: @Rchaeologist no worries, hope that helps you to write other loops in future work!